# Change position and scale on click with Velocity JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, velocity.js

I want to make a function which to scale and change the position of a button. When you click, I want it to transition to absolute center of the page and scale. Can't make it work, rookie here! Thanks!

```
<div id="carousel" class="carousel">
    <a href="project.html" class="thumb" id="thumb">
        <div class="tbTitle">
            <h2>Diamonds and Pearls</h2>
            <div class="vid-holder"></div>
        </div>
        <video src="img/01.mp4" type="video/mp4" loop muted autoplay playsinline></video>
    </a>
</div>
```

Css –

```
.thumb {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 640px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 3.5em;
}

.huge-thumb {
    max-width: 1280px;
    position: fixed;
}
```

jQuery –

```
$('#thumb').on("click", function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var scale = $("#thumb").height()/($("#huge-thumb").height() * 2);
    var toY = $("#thumb").offset().top - $("#huge-thumb").offset().top;  

    $.Velocity.animate($("#huge-thumb"), { translateY: toY, scaleX: scale, scaleY: scale, translateZ: 0 }, { delay: 1500, duration: 1050, easing: "easeInOutQuad" });
});
```

Comment: You are targeting another page to redirect the browser. How can you expect an animation in the page you are leaving?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're using Velocity V1 or V2 there, but as V1 is on the obsolete track I'm going to answer for V2 -

In Velocity V2 the various properties you are using don't exist (they don't exist in css, so you're not losing anything) - they are however values for the `transform` property, so you can use them properly instead.

You're also doing some really weird way of calling Velocity, so instead try this line change (line breaks for clarity):

`$("#huge-thumb").velocity({
   transform: [
      "translate(0," + toY + ") scale(" + scale + ")",
      "translate(0,0) scale(1)"
   ]
}, {
   delay: 1500,
   duration: 1050,
   easing: "easeInOutQuad"
});`

Transform itself has a few caveats, so that's using forcefeeding - the second line in the array says "move from 0,0, and scale from 1:1" - that's a general limit on transform, as the browser doesn't actually tell Velocity what the current transform is in a format it can use.